# what use of userdefined annotation witout any method?

Tags: java, annotations

In this code we have one user defined Annotation but without body any method what could be use of this

```
 import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
 import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
 import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
 import java.lang.annotation.Target;

 @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
 @Target( { ElementType.TYPE })
 public @interface InputBean {
 }
```

Comment: It could be used as just a marker/hint, or it could be used by an annotation processor someone there wrote. A quick google seems to indicate that it's not a standard annotation, so maybe you can look in your version control history to see who created that file, and ask them.

Comment: Marker annotation, same as a marker interface, but more annotationy.

Answer (score 1):

The `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)` tells us that whatever use it has, it's only at the source code level -- the annotation is forgotten by the time the compiler is done, and isn't in the generated class files.

That leaves two options:

- as a visual clue (ie, documentation) to human coders
- to be used by an [annotation processor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html)

Without knowing more, we can't tell which of those is the case here.